# fullcalendar in django 500 error

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to implement a calendar in my django app. I followed what this guy done in another post
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190670/fullcalendar-and-django)

When I go to app/cal I get a json response of all the entries. The page I implemented fullcalendar I get a 500 error.

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/cal/?start=2015-08-30&end=2015-10-11&_=1442333348614 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
```

Here is my code:

models.py

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    start = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def eventsFeed(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        print 'Its ajax from fullCalendar()'

    try:
        start = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(request.GET.get('start', False))).replace(tzinfo=utc)
        end = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(request.GET.get('end',False)))
    except ValueError:
        start = datetime.now.replace(tzinfo=utc)
        end = start + timedelta(days=7)

    entries = Entry.objects.all()
    print entries
    json_list = []
    for entry in entries:
        id = entry.id
        title = entry.title
        start = entry.start.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
        end = entry.end.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
        allDay = False

        json_entry = {'id':id, 'title':title, 'start':start, 'end':end, 'allDay':allDay}
        json_list.append(json_entry)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(json_list), content_type='application/json')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^cal/$', eventsFeed, name='cal'),
url(r'^calendar', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='cal/cal.html')),
```

views.py

```
def eventsFeed(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        print 'Its ajax from fullCalendar()'

    try:
        start = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(request.GET.get('start', False))).replace(tzinfo=utc)
        end = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(request.GET.get('end',False)))
    except ValueError:
        start = datetime.now.replace(tzinfo=utc)
        end = start + timedelta(days=7)

    entries = Entry.objects.all()
    print entries
    json_list = []
    for entry in entries:
        id = entry.id
        title = entry.title
        start = entry.start.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
        end = entry.end.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
        allDay = False

        json_entry = {'id':id, 'title':title, 'start':start, 'end':end, 'allDay':allDay}
        json_list.append(json_entry)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(json_list), content_type='application/json')
```

cal.html

```
<div id="calendar"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
                events: "/app/cal/"
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: If you're in DEBUG mode, the developer tools for your browser should show you the traceback from the ajax request. Please post it here if you can't figure out the problem from that.

Comment: Agreed with Alasdair: Error 500 means any error/exception when running Python code that is not catched as a Django exception (Like 404 errors).

Comment: I assumed it was a problem with the ajax. Once I checked for python errors it was easy to sort. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was `datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)` not `datetime.now.replace(tzinfo=utc)`